# Error : No Module named "xlwt"

Tags: python, import, xlwt

When i try to execute my code myfile.py from the terminal in ubuntu, showme this error : No Module named "xlwt", but when execute in Ninja no have problem.
python3.3

Comment: I wonder if you have two different Pythons installed. Try `import sys; print sys.version, sys.path` in each environment to determine if they are the same.

Comment: P.s. What is "Ninja"? Is it [Ninja-IDE](http://ninja-ide.org/)?

Comment: You are not providing enough info here, we can't help you with what you said

Comment: I'll bet Ninja is using a different python version than on the terminal.  At the top of `myfile.py`, add `import sys; print sys.executable`.  They probably point to different python versions.  You will need to install `xlwt` for both.

Answer (score 2):

To install the `xlwt` module in Ubuntu, try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-xlwt
```

---

From https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt, it appears that xlwt is not compatible with Python3.

Comment: I don't think xlwt is compatible with Python3.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```